# Panel scrolling on Android

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have list view is wrapped in a Panel. The scrolling works fine on Windows and IPad(2fingers) but I am unable to scroll on my Android Phone.

Here is my panel class

```
.panel { scrollbar-face-color: #47433F;scrollbar-track-color: #47433F; border: 5px ridge #CC6600;         width: 700px; height:800px;   overflow: scroll;}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Mohamed

Comment: An HTML source and jsfiddle sample would help

Comment: Hi Yuriy. My ASP Panel is <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" ScrollBars="vertical" Width="700px" Height="800px" CssClass="panel"  >. I am not sure what your mean jsFiddle. I am a newbie sorry. I appreciate you helping me. The scrolling works fine in all browsers (IE, FF, Safari and Chrome on windows). I am just having a problem on an Android Phone. Thank you again

Comment: jsFiddle means test site http://jsfiddle.net - copy/paste *renderd* html of relevant controls there along with related classes to see if you can recreate the issue there

Comment: I apologize if I was not clear but I am using ASP.net page (VB.net). I am  not sure if that is helpful to help me.

Comment: @Mohammed, I understand that, but ASP.NET renders as HTML markup in your browser - you can copy/paste **rendered** HTML into jsfiddle.

Comment: Yuriy, Thank you so much for your patience. As I explained I am having the issue when I try the website on Android phone. Here is the website URL http://aaagw2.itconceptsdesign.com/AAAGW2/Default2.aspx.... Thanks